# Matlab programming, Matrix sorting and ranking

Tags: matlab

Consider an example given below. There are 3 customers A, B,C.
1st row of matrix is the demand of respective customer and second row is the day when they need. 
for example: demand A=[10,40,50;15,45,75]; Customer A needs 10 items on 15th day.. 40 items on 45th day and 50 items on 75th day..Similarly for B,C.

```
 demand A=[10,40,50;15,45,75];
 demand B=[80,30,20;05,35,80];
 demand C=[50,40,30;20,47,88];
```

Now i need to rank the customer on basis of days. So here answer should be like 
rank 1: 5th day customer B 80 items
rank 2: 15th day customer A 10 items
rank 3: 20th day customer C 50 items.
and so on.

How can i do it in mat lab. so that when i rank it on basis of the day then I should then know how many items and which customer accordingly.

output should be like this:

```
                Rank  Customer  items  day
                  1     B        80     05
                  2     A        10     15
                  3     C        50     20
                  4     B        30     35
                  5     A        40     45
                  6     C        40     47
                  7     A        40     75
                  8     B        20     80 
                  9     C        30     88
```

Comment: Can you post what you actually expect the output to look like rather than trying to describe it in words?

Comment: Can you edit that into your question rather than putting it in the comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest the following approach:

**First stage**

generates a new matrix, which is the composition of A,B and C, such that:
The first col represents the day.
The second col represents the requested amount.
The third col is the costumer index (A=1,B=2,C=3).

```
res = [A',ones(size(A',1),1);B',ones(size(A',1),1)*2;C',ones(size(C',1),1)*3];
res(:,[2,1]) = res(:,[1,2]);
```

**Second stage**

sort the matrix according to the first column, which represents the day

```
[~,sortedDaysIndices] = sort(res(:,1));
res = res(sortedDaysIndices,:);
```

**Third stage: print the results**

```
for ii=1:size(res)
    if res(ii,3)==1
        costumerStr = 'A';
    elseif res(ii,3)==2
        costumerStr = 'B';
    else
        costumerStr = 'C';
    end

    fprintf('%s\n',[num2str(ii) ' ' costumerStr ' ' num2str(res(ii,2)) ' ' num2str(res(ii,1))])
end
```

**Result**

```
1 B 80 5
2 A 10 15
3 C 50 20
4 B 30 35
5 A 40 45
6 C 40 47
7 A 50 75
8 B 20 80
9 C 30 88
```